# How to handle @Html.LabelFor() if i am having 2 of them on the same page with one hidden and one is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
Try to click on the word Snacks.

<div hidden>
 <form action = "/Test/Index1" method = "post">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="Snacks">Snacks</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Snacks">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
<div>
 <form action = "/Test/Index2" method = "post">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="Snacks">Snacks</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Snacks">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

On click of that label it will check the 1st checkbox with the id="Snacks", which is inside the hidden div.
To know how it is working remove the hidden attribute of the first div and try it.

Comment: You cannot define two same ids in same html page.

Comment: Yes i know.. But as i am using Razor views and creating UI using @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Snacks) and @Html.CheckboxFor(m=>m.Snacks). So i cant change the id of any inputs.

Comment: I think you should tag `Razor` tag to your question. You should also post some code where you are using `@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Snacks)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define two `id="Snacks"` attribute in same page.

You can do something like this

```html
Try to click on the word Snacks.

<div>
 <form action = "/Test/Index1" method = "post">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="Snacks_1">Snacks</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Snacks_1" name="Snacks">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
<div>
 <form action = "/Test/Index2" method = "post">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="Snacks_2">Snacks</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Snacks_2" name="Snacks">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i know.. But as i am using 2 partial views and loading it with same model class and creating UI using tags Html Helpers like  @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Snacks) and @Html.CheckboxFor(m=>m.Snacks). So i cant change the id of any inputs. @Shubam